# How do i set up ajax nonce

Tags: ajax, nonce, endpoints

Follow the doc, I tried to set up X-WP-NONCE before ajax sent data to custom route, but it show wpApiSettings.nonce not defined. If don't set beforeSend, on the back end still can pass the nonce verify.

So just confused do I need to set up wpApiSettings.nonce before ajax send data.
Js files:

```
$('#person-register-form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(this);

    const fileInput = document.getElementById('proof_address_file');
    const files = fileInput.files;

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('proof_address_file', files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: data_obj.post_url,
        // beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        //     xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce);
        // },
        headers: {
            'X-WP-Nonce': data_obj.post_nonce,
        },
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });
});
```

PhP files:

```
    /**
 * Initialize Rest API routes
 */
public function init() {
    /**
     * Register a route for REST API
     */
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'register_route_api') );
}

/**
 * Register a route for REST API
 */
public function register_route_api() {

    register_rest_route(
        $this->route_namespace,
        $this->route,
        array(
            'methods' => $this->post_method,
            'callback' => array( $this, 'personal_post_callback' ),
        ),
        $this->override
    );
}

/**
 * Submit callback function
 *
 * @param $data
 *
 * @return WP_REST_Response
 */
public function personal_post_callback( $data ): WP_REST_Response {
    //Get ajax request headers
    $this->ajax_headers = $data -> get_headers();
    //Get ajax request params
    $this->ajax_data = $data -> get_params();
    //Get ajax request nonce
    $nonce = $this->ajax_headers['x_wp_nonce'][0];
    //Get ajax request files
    $this->ajax_file_data = $_FILES;

    echo json_encode( $this->ajax_headers );

    /**
     * Verify x_wp_nonce, if not pass, return 422 error.
     */
    if( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $this->nonce_title ) ){
        return new WP_REST_Response( 'Message not sent. Nonce verify not pass.', 422 );
    }

    $this->write_log( $this->ajax_data, $this->ajax_file_data );

    return new WP_REST_Response( 'Form submit success.', 200 );
}
```

Php files2:

```
    /**
 * Pass data to JavaScript.
 * @return bool
 */
public function wp_localize_script(): bool {
    global $wp_scripts;

    if ( ! ( $wp_scripts instanceof WP_Scripts ) ) {
        _wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, 'personal-form-info' );
        return false;
    }

    return $wp_scripts->localize( 'personal-form-submit-ajax', 'data_obj',
        array(
            'post_url' => get_rest_url( null, 'tantech-form-post/v1/' . 'personal-post' ),
            'post_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Call CreateRsetAPI class and get route registered
 * @return void
 */
public function create_reset_api() {

    new CreateRestAPI( 'tantech-form-post/v1/', 'personal-post', 'POST', false, 'wp_rest', $this->plugin_Path );

}
```

Comment: Your nonce is on `data_obj.post_nonce`. That's what you defined in your PHP. You got an error because you were trying to use `wpApiSettings.nonce` for some reason?

Comment: So that means the wp_create_nonce and wpApiSettings.nonce are two nonce verify method, i don't need to add wpApiSettings.nonce before ajax sent. By the way, is the x_wp_nonce will add to ajax response automaticly?

Comment: they're variables, and nowhere in your PHP code did you localize a `nonce` variable in `wpApiSettings`. You did however create an appropriate nonce in your second PHP file named `post_nonce` on `data_obj` but for some reason chose not to use it

Comment: also you don't need to verify and authenticate the user with `if( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $this->nonce_title ) ){` in your REST API callbacks, WordPress does that for you behind the scenes. You're meant to give it a `permission_callback` when you register your rest route ( your error log is going to be full of warnings about this ), so that you can check if the current user is able to access this endpoint, aka do they have the right capabilitiy, etc, but you're not meant to check nonces or sign users in etc, WordPress takes care of figuring out who the user is for you